# Class and Object Microsoft Visual Studio Errors

Tags: c++, class, object

I have to make a c++ problem for school with Classes and Object.

Create "Shaorma" class.

-member data:meat,garlic,salt,peper;

-member functions:implicit constructors, parameters

-constructors,functions for printing on

-screen,functions that modifies "garlic" member type,function that

-return meat,destructor;

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and i get these errors:

-Error  2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals;

-Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall shaorma::shaorma(void)" (??0shaorma@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class shaorma
{
int salt, peper;
char meat[40];
char garlic[3];

public:
shaorma();
shaorma(int, int, char*, char*);
~shaorma();
void print();
void setgarlic(char*);
char* getmeat();
};

shaorma::shaorma(int s, int p, char *C, char *U)
{
salt = s;
peper = p;
strcpy_s(meat, C);
strcpy_s(garlic, U);
}

shaorma::~shaorma()
{
cout << "The destructor war called.";
}

void shaorma::print()
{
cout << "Shaorma has garlic:" << garlic;
cout << "," << salt << "salt";
cout << peper << "peper";
cout << "meat type:" << meat << endl;
}

void shaorma::setgarlic(char *U)
{
strcpy_s(garlic, U);
}

char* shaorma::getmeat()
{
return meat;
}

void main()
{
shaorma S1, S2(5, 4, "yes", "lamb");
S1.print();
S2.print();
S1.setgarlic("No");
S2.getmeat();
cout << "Meat is :" << S2.getmeat();
_getch();

}
```

Comment: Where is the body for your default constructor?

Comment: `shaorma S1, S2(5, 4, "yes", "lamb");` only the second receives those parameters. The first is created with the default constructor. Also do you have your meat and garlic parameters the right way round? Why not use `std::string` so you can have meats with any name, and set garlic to a `bool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared default constructor `shaorma()` but forgot to define it

```
class shaorma
{
//...
public:
    shaorma();
    //...
```

This constructor is used in declaration of object `S1` in statement of main

```
shaorma S1, S2(5, 4, "yes", "lamb");
```

Take into account that main shall have return type `int`

```
int main()
```

Also string literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. As you are using string literals in your program then for example function `setgarlic` should be declared like

```
void setgarlic( const char* );
```

Comment: It worked but now i have another problem.L"Buffer is too small" && 0

Comment: @ Andrei Gabriel You defined garlic as having only 3 characters but are trying to copy at least 5 characters of string literal "lamb"

Comment: It worked! Sry for noob errors but i"m at the beggining and i try to understand all the errors and code.Thanks a lot!